# Passing a variable between two function

Tags: bash, shell

in my bash script i try to pass from the function ( function_2 ) a variable to the function ( function_1 ) unfortunately  i didn't find how to do it properly :(
I search on internet but all the time i fall on different language ( ruby, python etc .. ) i try to do the same without success :(

```
function_1(){
   echo "The value of : $VAR in function_2"
}


function_2(){
   echo "the value of var if function_1 is : $VAR "
   function_1
}

while getopts s: opt; do
    case $opt in
        s) VAR=$OPTARG
           function_2
           ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments passed to functions as parameters in *bash* are accessible with `$1`, `$2`...

```
function_1() {
   echo "The value of passed parameter in function_2 is: $1"
}


function_2() {
   echo "the value of var in function_1 is: $VAR"
   function_1 $VAR
}

while getopts s: opt; do
    case $opt in
        s) VAR=$OPTARG
           function_2
           ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass on the variable as argument to the function when you call the function_1 for example:

```
function_1(){
   VAR=$1
   echo "The value of : $VAR in function_2"
}


function_2(){
   echo "the value of var if function_1 is : $VAR "
   function_1 $VAR
}

while getopts s: opt; do
    case $opt in
        s) VAR=$OPTARG
           function_2
           ;;
    esac
done
```

**notice that you can directly access the passed on variable as $1 in function_1 without assigning it to VAR**